# 401: unauthorized issue in Web API .net core C#

Tags: c#, reactjs, azure-active-directory, authorization, webapi

```
    I am getting JWT Token from the React UI using AcquireTokenSilent of MSAL. Now, I have to call Graph API using this token in Web API(.net core) in C#.
    Before calling the Graph API I am getting "401 :Unauthorized". Please help me in resolving the issue.       
    
    In Startup.cs I am using following code:
    ----------
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
                {
                    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration,"AzureAd")
                            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
                }
        
        
          public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
               {
                   app.UseAuthentication();
                   app.UseRouting();
                   app.UseAuthorization();
               }
        
       
         In ProfileController.cs
        
         [HttpPost]
                public async Task<ActionResult> PostProfileItem([FromBody]SetProfile setprofile)
                {
                     
                    HttpContext.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(scopeRequiredByApi);
                     
                    try
                    {
                        List<HeaderOption> requestHeaders = new List<HeaderOption>() { new HeaderOption("Authorization", "Bearer " + setprofile.access_token) };
                        User profile = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request(requestHeaders).GetAsync();
                }
               (catch Exception ex)
                {
                }
              return Ok(profile);
            }
        
            SetProfile.cs
        namespace Web.Dto
        {
            public record SetProfile
            {
               [NotMapped]
               [JsonProperty("access_token")]
               [Required]
                public string access_token { get; init; }
               
            }
        
            
        }
```

### React UI code acquiring the token and posting the access token to the ProfileController.cs

### if (!graphData && inProgress === InteractionStatus.None) { //instance of Form Data let formData = new FormData() // Acquire token silent instance.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest) //then clause .then((accessTokenResponse) => { // Acquire token silent success let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken; //logging access token console.log(`access token : ${accessToken}`) //code to add access token in API formData.append("access_token", accessToken) //call to profile API props.userProfileCall(formData) }); //code to catch error }).catch((error) => { //logging error console.log(error); })

Comment: It would be better to show us your React part. How do you pass the token?

Comment: I have added the React part. Please help me.

Comment: Few things need to be confirmed, does your token has required permission for the `graph api` you are trying to call? another thing is could you [check your token here](https://jwt.io/) to double check if is valid as per your context?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

**1)** To access any web API from Reactjs or any Ajax method Web API must enable [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

You need to set CORS policy to be able to call the API in **Startup.cs**.

```
 services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("default", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
    })
```

**2)** In your controller, add **[Authorize]** decorator, which will make sure all incoming requests have an authentication bearer

Example:

```
 [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
    }
```

**Solution 2:**
Make sure you grant the **User.Read.All** Application permission.

1. Sign in to the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/).
2. If you have access to multiple tenants, use the **Directory + subscription** filter   in the top menu to select the tenant containing your client app's registration.
3. Select **Azure Active Directory > App registrations**, and then select your client application.
4. Select **API permissions > Add a permission > Microsoft Graph > Application permissions**.

[image]

5. All permissions exposed by Microsoft Graph are shown under **Select permissions**.

[image]

6. Select the **User.Read.All** and click on  **Add permissions**
   [image]

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview)